# css3 multiple background images shorthand doesn't work

Tags: css

I try to put 2 img within a div background, I want to code to be as clean as possible, I used the below shorthand, but it doesn't seem work

```
background: #ECF0F1 url('../img/7Pxborder.png') 0px 38px repeat-x,
#ECF0F1 url('../img/7Pxborder_2.png') 0px 75px repeat-x;
```

neither this

```
background: #ECF0F1 url('../img/7Pxborder.png') 0px 38px repeat-x,
url('../img/7Pxborder_2.png') 0px 75px repeat-x;
```

Comment: This is the syntax that is supposed to work in browsers that support it: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/.  An example from that page: `background: url(sheep.png) center bottom no-repeat, url(betweengrassandsky.png) left top no-repeat;`

Comment: @jfriend00 no browser issue here, i tried one background it work

Comment: My point was that only modern browsers support multiple backgrounds.  For example, IE 8 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color goes last and only once.

```
background: url('../img/7Pxborder.png') 0px 38px repeat-x,
            url('../img/7Pxborder_2.png') 0px 75px repeat-x #ECF0F1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wAFtC/

You can find this detailed in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background).  Notice that only `<final-bg-layer>` contains a background color.

Answer (score 0):

got it now, it's stacking issue..

```
background: url('../img/7Pxborder.png') 0px 38px repeat-x, // index is higher
#ECF0F1  url('../img/7Pxborder_2.png') 0px 75px repeat-x;
```